# n number of 1s using binary operations

Tags: c, binary, numbers

Is there any way to get  `n` number of `1`s using only these binary operations ( `!`, `~`, `&`, `^`, `|`, `+`, `<<`, `>>` ) where `n` is an input?

Example,

```
n ---> output
0 ---> 0000
1 ---> 0001
2 ---> 0011
3 ---> 0111
4 ---> 1111
...
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What have you tried? (It can be done with two operations).

Comment: If you allow `~` and `+` you might as well allow `-` (because `x - y == ~(~x + y)`)

Comment: Starting from a=0; a=a+a+1; (There's no need to have an explicit formula, as one can do it iteratively. `a+a` can be done with a shift `<<` and `+` can be replaced with `|` or `^`. )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
// Since "-" is not on your list while "+" is, I'll add negative 1
// using `~0`; this assumes that your computer uses 2's complement
// representation of negative numbers.
(1 << n) + ~0;
```

The idea is that `1 << n` produces a power of two: `1`, `10`, `100`, `1000`, and so on. Adding a negative one produces `2^n-1`, which is what your pattern represents.

Comment: What is the format specifier to use for the printf() to print this?I used `%d` and it's simply printing the value in the decimal system.If I use n=3, then it prints 7, but I want it as `111`.How to do it?

Comment: Please tell me how to do that, ie to display 7 as 111.It's embarrassing to ask something that simple, but it's worse never to learn

Comment: @SheerFish: AFAIK there's no standard `printf` specifier to print in binary, but writing a decimal to binary converter is quite straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can do

`~(~(1<<n) + 1)`

Example:

Say n is 2.

1. ~(~(1<<2) + 1)
2. ~(~(100) + 1)
3. ~(111..1011 + 1)
4. ~(111..1100 )

   = 11